# '*' in Gurobi Constraint

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm working with gurobi and the python interface right now and found the following constraint. Could anyone of you please tell me what the '*' is doing here?

Thanks!

```
model.addConstrs((OverManned.sum('*', year) <= MaxOverManning for year in years), "Overmanning")
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, '*' just stand for any value is accepted.